# Map<String, dynamic> to any type of Map without knowing data in advance

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json response from a server and the format is as follows....

```
{
  key1: {
     subKey1: value1
     subKey2: value2
     [...]   
  },
  key2: {
    [...]
  },
  [...]
}
```

All the answers I've come accross suggest mapping directly to PODOs with predefined Model classes with fromJson(...).

However, this JSON is for translation strings and is gigantic. top level keys are language codes, but these can be hundreds of entries, and the sub level keys are in the hundreds as well, and their names may change at any time, etc.

Isnt there a simple way to go **from Map<String, dynamic>** which jsonDecode(response.body) gives me **to Map<String, Map<String,String>>** ?

I've tried doing

```
Map<String, Map<String, String> typedMap = jsonResponse.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value))
```

but I'm told the formats don't match.

Here's an edited output based on suggestions,

Full sample code first... Get.find<> is from the GetX package for state management. It works just fine in other areas of the project.

```
class TranslationsService {
  final logger = getLogger('Translation Service');

  Future<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> getTranslations() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        [url]);

    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      var jsonResponse =
          convert.json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = jsonResponse
          .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value as Map<String, String>));

      logger.i(result);
      return result;
    } else {
      logger.e('Request failed with status code ${response.statusCode}');
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future load() async {
    final api = TranslationsService();
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = await api.getTranslations();
    Get.find<TranslatedStrings>().map = map;
  }
}
```

And the output, which is even more error filled now...

```
E/flutter (26806): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' in type cast
E/flutter (26806): #0      TranslationsService.getTranslations.<anonymous closure> 
package:dream_x/services/translations_service.dart:19
E/flutter (26806): #1      MapMixin.map  (dart:collection/maps.dart:170:28)
E/flutter (26806): #2      TranslationsService.getTranslations 
package:dream_x/services/translations_service.dart:19
E/flutter (26806): <asynchronous suspension>
[....]
I/example.dream_(26806): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
```

I might be stupid here, but it seems overly complex to convert a simple map..... :D

And, just as proof that the response I'm getting is not some fluke, here's the full output of a print of jsonResponse with a temporary truncated file, formated and validated with JSON Formatter:

```
{
   "en":{
      "title":"Title English",
      "label_search":"Search",
      "label_profile":"Profile",
      "label_dashboard":"Dashboard"
   },
   "fr":{
      "title":"Title French",
      "label_search":"Recherche",
      "label_profile":"Profil",
      "label_dashboard":"Tableau de bord"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might stem from a misunderstanding on my part where I'm too used to Javascript that can read JSON outright and does not need to explicitly convert it to an interface of known properties in advance.

As such, I have decided to proceed differently. I have used [QuickType](https://quicktype.io/) to get the boiler plate code based on a reduced data set and I added the known properties to the boilerplate afterwards. When properties are added, they will be added directly to the object structure.

Not optimal, but we don't want to fight too much for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sure they will always be string, you can use `value.toString()`

```
Map<String, Map<String, String> typedMap = jsonResponse.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am, however, getting this error when trying to access it after the cast... Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Map<String, String>>' in type cast) Any ideas?

Comment: This means we need to nest the map another level deeper. `_InternalLinkedHashMap` translates to `Map`.

Comment: So .map on the KeyEntry aswell? I'm confused to be honest. I've dealt with JSON multiple times before, in various environments, but this is throwing me for a loop...

Comment: `.toString()` is going to convert the submap into a `String` instead of a `Map<String,String>`. Hence, the cast error. Check my answer for correction https://stackoverflow.com/a/67457443/13973939

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You were on the right track by using `jsonResponse.map` for the most part, except that you misunderstood what the map callback returns.

```
jsonResponse.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value)
```

- The `key` here is your top level key. It's going to change like "key1", "key2" ...
- The `value` here is your Map<dynamic,dynamic> that is in front of the key. This is what it essentially holds:

```dart
//Dart is parsing this as Map<dynamic, dynamic> probably
{
  subkey1: value1,
  subKey2: value2
}
```

### Solution

All you need to do is cast the `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` to `Map<String,String>`  <strike>using the `as` keyword.</strike>

```dart
Map<String,Map<String,String>> result = jsonResponse.map(
    (key, value) => MapEntry(key,value as Map<String,String>)
  );
```

---

### Update

Casting can be done using any of these two methods

1. `Map<T1,T2>.from`, where T1 and T2 are your target types:

   ```dart
   MapEntry(key, Map<String, String>.from(value))
   ```
2. `Map.castFrom<S1,S2,T1,T2>`, where S1 and S2 are your source types and T1 and T2 are your target types:

   ```dart
   MapEntry(key, Map.castFrom<String, dynamic, String, String>(value))
   ```

### Output

Printing runtime types:

```dart
print("${jsonResponse.runtimeType}");
print("${result.runtimeType}");
```

This is what it prints

```
JsLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> //<-- jsonResponse
JsLinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>> //<-- result
```

Comment: I understand your explanation, and it seems very logical to me. However, after attempts, I still come across a typing error, now with the Map<String, String>... I have edited the original post with current progress. Any chance it gives you more context / ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Funny thing is I know what you're saying makes sense. It should not cause issues, and yet, when using both of your methods to cast the MapEntry value, I'm getting the same error, which is...

MapEntry(key, Map<String, String>.from(value))
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

I'm starting to get annoyed... just a bit... :D Thanks for trying!

Comment: @aLx450 can you print the value of jsonResponse just before .map and update the question with the output. I wanna see what it holds.